# Need to replace control characters in a parquet file which is stored in hdfs

Tags: apache-spark, hive, apache-pig, parquet

I am importing data from MySQL to hdfs as a parquet file and constructing a hive external table over it but there are few unwanted control characters in that file which are also being loaded to the hive table. I need to replace those with an empty string. I tried with pig but had no luck with it. Following is the spark code which is returning an issue.

PYSPARK CODE:

```
sc = spark.sparkContext
# using SQLContext to read parquet file
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext
sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)
# to read parquet file
df = sqlContext.read.parquet('path-to-file/file.parquet')
df1= df.replace(['\xa0'],[''])
df1.write.parquet('path-to-file/replaced_files')
```

ISSUE:

UnicodeDecodeError utf8 codec can't decide byte 0xa0 in position 0 : invalid start byte

Please suggest me how I could solve this spark issue and also let me know if we could handle these control characters using PIG or any other way.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: How are you getting data to HDFS. Are you using SQOOP? If so, you can consider replacing these in the SQOOP script?

Comment: Yeah!! I am importing data through sqoop. How can we replace in the sqoop script?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SQOOP, Use the --query option in the import command and use the replace statement below to replace the xa0, which is a char(160) as per the unicode character set

```
replace(input_string, char(160), ' ')
```

Comment: I am importing all the columns and I am not sure of the columns count and their names. So how can I implement this?

Comment: are you saying that you don't know the structure of the data you are importing? That's a bit worrying. Have you tried to import as text file and tried your pyspark script. If that works, you can them apply parquet to the transformed data?